# Is change management certification valuable?

Tags: certification, change-management

Along the same lines as [this question on PM certification](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/871/is-the-pmp-or-other-project-management-certification-worth-while-to-have), I'm trying to work out the value of *change* management certification. Note that here I'm talking about managing and gaining acceptance for organizational changes and not how to control changes to a project plan.

I am a firm believer that the premise that effective organizational change management helps realize the benefits of a project or program, so see value in training in this space. Where things are less clear for me is whether or not certification is a useful thing to promote on a resume. Even if there isn't much demand today (and looking at job boards tends to make me think there isn't), there is nothing wrong with being an early adopter of something that is on an upward trajectory.

The main standards that I'm aware of include [Prosci](http://www.prosci.com/), which apparently has 20k+ certified practitioners, and a new certification program that the [Association of Change Management Professionals](http://www.acmpglobal.org/) is planning to release next year. My main qualm with ACMP is that their membership is orders of magnitude smaller than that of PMI so I'm not sure how credible they are.

So my question is: Is Change Management certification valuable to have either based on demand today or potential demand in the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Change management is too broad topic, and change managers have almost no respect nowadays.

Based on my observations certifications works only if they are for a very specific and rare field or requires a very specific and rare skill set. For example, cisco telecommunication systems, AIX operator, or Oracle database specialist. Unfortunately for you, change management does fall into this category. It can mean coaching, mentoring, "new age" management etc, and none of these are specific or rare. There are a lot these on the market and the **differentiation factor is the references and experience.**

If you are looking for something that sticks out and makes you different from other change managers, collect proper references from companies that matter, and from organisations that changed on the highest level possible , minimum a department with medium size (> 150 people).

Answer (score 0):

> Is Change Management certification valuable to have

Depends on your definition of value.

If I can rephrase: "Will CM certification help me get a job or help me earn more?"

Probably not. Experience is many orders of magnitude more valuable than a methodology certification. Being an early adopter is all well and good, but what's the value in it? Certification only has value *now* - being certified for X number of years holds no weight.

If I were you I'd wait to see whether Job Ads started to pick this up as a requirement or a desirable. Then it may hold value to you - and then it may be worth getting at that time. As of now I'd say it'll just be expensive bragging rights (and usually access to some "exclusive" forums and a few PDFs).